# Set value with parameter decorator

Tags: typescript, typescript-decorator

I'm trying to create a Parameter Decorators but i don't get it.
What i want is to have a function with a decorator who define my variable value

```
class A {
public hello(@helloWorld() hey: string){
  console.log(hey) // should be equal to "Hello World"
 }
}
```

I would like to use it in my api so I can inject the context of my incoming request in this scope.

What is typescript documentation is saying:

```
NOTE: A parameter decorator can only be used to observe that a parameter has been declared on a method.
```

[Typescript doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#parameter-decorators)
But I saw nestJs done this with the @Body() and when looking the source code I still don't get It. They never return a value they work with Reflect

Comment: They are using 'reflect-metadata' just to hold *shared state*, i.e. just as a global variable...

Comment: Please include your attempted decorator implementation thus far.

Comment: You can check here where I have my attempted decorator : https://github.com/webagency-jt/client_app_api/tree/dev/src/libs/core/decorators